# JavaFX - Auto increment ID

Tags: java, javafx, increment

This is what I have

```
public class AddNewCategoryController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField name;

    @FXML
    private TextField description;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    }

    public void save(){
        final AtomicLong identifier = new AtomicLong(5);
        Long id = identifier.incrementAndGet();
        String catgoryName = name.getText();
        String categoryDescription = description.getText();

        Category category = new Category(id,catgoryName,categoryDescription);

        ReadingDataFromFiles.writeCategory(category);

    }
}
```

When the programs runs there's a screen to add a new category and the user has to write category's name and description but ID should be automatic and should be increased every time the user enters a new Category. The way I've done it doesn't work as intended, it's increased only once but since initial value stays 5 it's always 6.

Comment: Do not create new AtomicLong whenever `save` is invoked. Make `AtomicLong identifier` a field and initialize it once.

Answer (score 2):

Move this line:

```
final AtomicLong identifier = new AtomicLong(5);
```

… higher up, outside the method, to be a member field on the class.

In your existing code, each call to that `save` method is creating a new `AtomicLong` to replace the previous one. So your counting cannot accumulate.

Proper naming can help clarify. That `AtomicLong` is not an “identifier”. It is an “identifierGenerator”. Each number returned by its `incrementAndGet` method is the “identifier”.